# pdftk outputting PDFs with artifacts on pages

Tags: java, pdf, pdftk

I am using pdftk to collect specific PDF pages and output them to a new PDF file.  Most of the pages are fine, but I am finding artifacts on some of the pages.  The artifacts are usually similar and appear in about the same place on the page. Two examples that appear on one page are: "6_DirLine" and "6_NumList."

I'm using pdftk in a simple script (so maybe that's where the problem originates), but am wondering if this might be a problem introduced by the pdftk program itself.  (Also: I'm just a school teacher trying to solve a problem at work, not a developer.)

```
echo "What PDF pages do you want to save? (Hint: use a single space between numbers.)"
read PAGE1
var=$(echo $PAGE1)
pdftk "$*" cat $var output "QuickQuiz'$var'".pdf
```

Comment: Can you supply the input or output file?

Comment: The extra stuff appearing on the page is Optional Content. It looks like pdftk is deleting the Optional Content dictionary when splitting the file, so content which should be suppressed no longer is. So it looks like pdftk won't work for this. Try another PDF splitter like qpdf or cpdf and see if that works for you.

Comment: @johnwhitington Thank you for your help!  I tested qpdf and it introduced the same artifacts.  I will test out cpdf, but I might just have to do all of this manually.  This project is for all elementary grades in a school district, so the scripts would save me many hours of tedious work, but I can't sink too much more time into trying out tools.  Thanks again!

Comment: Installed cpdf using pipx.  When I try "cpdf in.pdf 277,287 -o out.pdf" I get an error message saying " No such command 'in.pdf'."  Tried using full path to in.pdf and also tried "./cpdf in.pdf . . ." but still get same error.  "which cpdf" shows its installed in /home/bwoah/.local/bin/cpdf.

Comment: This is not the cpdf in question - it is a different python program named cpdf. Get cpdf from https://community.coherentpdf.com/

Comment: Thanks, @johnwhitington!  I had overlooked the link for pre-build cpdf. cpdf  worked great and did not produce the same artifacts that other tools introduced.  Thanks again!